# [Java]Null value in String Array when int inserted

Tags: java, arrays, null

I'm declaring a String array of [2][5]. Up until that point everything is fine. I can insert things into the array.

But when I insert an integer value into the array, 'null' keyword is automatically added before that int value.

So let's say I inserted 5 into arrayName[1][0]. When I print it afterwards I get 'null5'. Which is weird.

What exactly you guys think the problem is. Thanks, C@N.

Comment: Could you post some code, please?

Comment: Why do u insert int to a String type array anyway ?

Comment: The problem is clear: Why do you insert integers into a String array? Call `array[n][m]=String.valueOf(value)`.

Comment: You definitely need to post **how** you insert the 5 into the array. `arrayName[1][0] = 5;` does not work. Neither does `arrayName[1][0] = new Integer(5);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see this happening is if you use +=:

```
String[] a = new String[1];
a[0] += 1;
System.out.println(a[0]);
```

Cause if you just use `a[0] = 1;` you would get compile error.
The reason you get null5 is because you are concatenating the string "null" with 5:

```
a[0] = (String) null + 1
```

So the question is what are you trying to achieve? Simply setting the value or adding to it?

If you just want to set it use:

```
String[] a = new String[1];
a[0] = Integer.toString(1);
System.out.println(a[0]);
```

If you do want to append to it:

```
String[] a = new String[1];
if (a[0] == null) {
    a[0] = Integer.toString(1);
} else {
    a[0] += 1;
}
System.out.println(a[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks pal. Just what I needed. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `+=` to add items, then I think this could happen. Use `String.valueOf()`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any String variable let say **myString** (as a instance variable having default value null) and doing someting like this -

```
int i=5;
myString = myString+i;
```

because you are not initializing String mystring it get default value **null** and add up with i.

This may be one of the situation.